# How to use microsoft access or sql pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to use microsoft access or query to change from table1

```
student name    course_attended date    quiz score
john            course 1    3/1/2017    98
carl            course 1    3/1/2017    90
george          course 1    3/1/2017    77
john            course 2    3/5/2017    99
carl            course 2    3/5/2017    96
george          course 2    3/5/2017    80
john            course 3    4/4/2017    77
carl            course 3    4/4/2017    80
george          course 3    4/4/2017    85
```

to table2

```
student name    course 1    course 2    course 3
john            3/1/2017    3/5/2017    4/4/2017
                98          99          95
carl            3/1/2017    3/5/2017    4/4/2017
                90          96          89
george          3/1/2017    3/5/2017    4/4/2017
                77          80          85
```

Basically, with select distinct [student name] use transformation and pivot
to change from table1 to table2. Please help. I would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: If you’re using Microsoft Access, try out the Cross Tab wizard.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do any calcs on the output, try:

```
TRANSFORM First([attend_date] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [quiz_score]) AS Data
SELECT student_name
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY student_name
PIVOT course;
```

Date is a reserved word. Should not use reserved words as names. Also, avoid spaces and special characters/punctuation (underscore only exception) in names.

Comment: Hi all, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,
TRANSFORM First([date_a] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [quiz_score]) AS Data
SELECT student_name
FROM tbl_quiz
GROUP BY student_name
PIVOT course_attended;

and the query does not show the quiz_score. However, the form created from the query result shows it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Expand the height of the query rows and you should see the score. Why create a form since the output is not editable? Should this really be a report? Also, if answer resolves your issue, would be nice to mark it as accepted.